# Binary Search Algorithm: Text File for each record in array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, text, binary

I've got an array with 90,000 integers and also have a txt file , 
I have to read the txt file sequentially and am not allowed to put it into an array , Foreach record in the text file
file I have to find the corresponding number in the array using binary search.then display how many matching numbers.

this is how I done it but it only finds the first matching number then stops

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //etc(OTHER CODE).......................
    Array.Sort(NumFile);
    // BINARY SEARCHHHH
    int last,
    first,
    mid = 0,
    target,
    found = 0,
    counter = 0;
    string run;

    //Stats
    int Finds = 0;
    first = 0;
    last = NumFile.Length - 1;            
    //READ TextFile
    StreamReader search = new StreamReader("Records.txt");
    target = int.Parse(search.ReadLine());
    //while (last >= first && found == 0)
    while (last >= first && found == 0 && (run = search.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        mid = (last + first) / 2;
        if (target == NumFile[mid])
        {
            found = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (target < NumFile[mid])
            {
                 last = mid - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                 first = mid + 1;
            }

        }
        if (found == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe number was found at location {0}", mid);
            Finds++;
        }
        else
        {
             //Console.WriteLine("\nNumber not found");                  
        }

    }

    Console.WriteLine("Binary Search Statistics \t Hits:{0} ,hits);        

}    .
```

Comment: I don't understand why you keep reading the file (into "run") in your binary search loop. It probably skipped over the whole file whilst looking for the first number. I think you want two nested loops: the file reading loop outside and the search loop inside.

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Why don't you just call [Array.BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is your while loop look at the while condition found == 0

```
while (last >= first && found == 0 && (run = search.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    mid = (last + first) / 2;
    if (target == NumFile[mid])
    {
        found = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (target < NumFile[mid])
        {
             last = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
             first = mid + 1;
        }

    }
    if (found == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe number was found at location {0}", mid);
        Finds++;
    }
    else
    {
         //Console.WriteLine("\nNumber not found");                  
    }

}
```

So inside where found == 1 if statement you need to make found to = 0 so it continues in the loop

```
if (found == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe number was found at location {0}", mid);
    Finds++;
    found =0;
}
```